# codeigniter captcha helper not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Captcha images are not creating inside the `images` folder**

```
  public function index()
  {
       $this->load->helper('captcha');
       $capt = array ('img_path' => './images/',
                      'img_url' =>   base_url() .'images/',
                      'font_path' => base_url().'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
                      'img_width' => '150',
                      'img_height' => 24,
                      'border' => 0,
                      'expiration' => 7200);

       $result = create_captcha($capt);
       $this->load->view('captchaDisplay',$result);
  }
```

**View the captcha in captchaDisplay.php**

```
<?php 
  echo $result ['image'];
 ?>
```

Comment: Does root path having folder call `images` ???

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, file Structure should be

```
application
images
System
index.php
.htaccess
```

---

**In Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('captcha');
    $capt = array ( 
        'img_path' => './images/', # root path
        'img_url' =>   base_url() .'images/',  # root path
        'font_path' => base_url().'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
        'img_width' => '150',
        'img_height' => 24,
        'border' => 0,
        'expiration' => 7200
    );
    $result['image'] = create_captcha($capt);
    $this->load->view('captchaDisplay',$result);
}
```

To show in view - [Check this link](https://www.codexworld.com/implement-captcha-codeigniter-captcha-helper/)

Answer (score 0):

Error lies here: `echo $result ['image'];`

From:

```
$result = create_captcha($capt);
$this->load->view('captchaDisplay',$result);
```

You are passing an array `$result` which contains `word` `image` .etc. To access in your view you can do `echo $image;` or better yet:

```
$result = create_captcha($capt);
$this->load->view('captchaDisplay', array('captcha' => $result);
```

and access in view via: `echo $captcha['image'];`

The latter is a better method if you plan on adding more view items.